# turbo c guessing game with do/while loop

Tags: loops, do-while, turbo-c

I've made a simple program in Turbo C which acts like a guessing game. It should end the game after the user inputs 3 wrong characters, or as soon as the correct one is guessed. However it doesn't work and I can't figure out why. The game just closes after I input 4 characters (wrong or not).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void main(void)
{
char ch;
int tries = 0;
int win_flag = 0;

clrscr();


printf("Guess the letter: ");

do
{
    ch = getch();
    printf("%c", ch);
    tries++;
    if (ch == 'a')
        win_flag = 1;
    else
        win_flag = 0;
}
while (tries <= 3 || win_flag == 1);

if (tries <= 3)
    printf("\nGame over.");
else if (win_flag == 1)
    printf("\nYou win!");

getch();
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your loop condition as

```
while (tries <= 3 && win_flag == 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You forgot to handle the `enter` keys people press after each character. So your next `getch` is getting them.
2. Your `while` clause is busted. You want to keep looping so long as the person still has tries left and the win flag is still zero. So: `(tries <= 3) && (win_flag == 0)`